# Trigonometric inequality to prove

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Prove the following inequality for each $x$:

$$|\sin x+7\cos x| \leq \sqrt{50}$$

My remark: It seems to me that the solution uses the fact that $1^2+7^2=50$.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways is to use the addition formula: $R \sin (a+x) = (R\cos a) \sin x + (R\sin a) \cos x$. We let $R \cos a = 1$ and $R \sin a = 7$. Hence $50 = 1^2 + 7^2 = R^2 (\cos^2 + \sin^2) = R^2$ and $R = \sqrt{50}$.

$|\sin x + 7\cos x| = |\sqrt{50} \sin (a+x)| \leq \sqrt{50}$

Answer (score 3):

$$(1\sin x + 7\cos x)^2 < (1^2 + 7^2)[(\sin x)^2 + (\cos x)^2] = 50$$

and take square root both sides to get the answer.

Comment: You have essentially used Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity(http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity), I think we should replace $<$ with $\le$ as $(ad+bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)-(ac-bd)^2\le (a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Or Cauchy Schwarz inequality.